# Vim warning I/O redirect to/from terminal with git rebase command

Tags: ruby, git, vim

Trying to `rebase HEAD~5 and squash 5 commits together into 1` from 10 dummy commits using `ruby`, `system command`.
   Using `vim` as default editor and getting this error:

```
# ERROR
# Vim  warning: output does not redirect on terminal
# Vim  warning: input does not come from terminal
```

Trying to do:

```
# DESIRED
# 1. open VIM terminal window
# 2. manualy select files for squashing

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# create dummy files
1.upto(10) { |i| `touch  "file#{i}.txt"`  }

files = Dir.glob('*.txt')

# initialize repo
`git init`

# commit each file separately
files.each do |f|
`git add #{f}`
`git commit -m "add #{f} to repo"`
end

# rebasing
`git rebase -i HEAD~5`
# error
```

Any ideas how to make it working and what to improve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the above code is that you are trying to run an external command (in this case, `vim` via git's inbuilt rebase command) from ruby using the backticks operator.

Instead, try and use `system` command for this purpose.
Reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system

So, the corrected code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# DESIRED
# 1. open VIM terminal window
# 2. manualy select files for squashing

# create dummy files
1.upto(10) { |i| `touch  "file#{i}.txt"`  }

files = Dir.glob('*.txt')

# initialize repo
system "git init"

# commit each file separately
files.each do |f|
system "git add #{f}"
system "git commit -m 'add #{f} to repo'"
end

# rebasing
system "git rebase -i HEAD~5"
# error
```